# AZDATA BDC CREATE stuck. Control containers pending. Scheduling error on NFS PVC

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I am very new to Linux, Docker and Kubernetes. I need to setup an on-premises POC to showcase BDC.

What I have installed.
1. Ubuntu 19.10 
2. Kubernetes Cluster
3. Docker
4. NFS
5. Settings and prerequisites but obviously missing stuff.

This has been done with stitched together tutorials. I am stuck on "AZDATA BDC Create". Error below.
[Scheduling error on POD PVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBU3T.png).

Some more information.

[NFS information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBz8v.png)

[Storage class info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm3DW.png)

More Info 20191220:
[PV & PVcs bound NFS side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSQJI.png)

Comment: Have you already solved this problem ?

Comment: I have not. Currently unable to work on it. Busy looking for a resource to help sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic Volume Provisioning** alongside with a StorageClass allows the cluster to provision PersistentVolumes on demand. In order to make that work, the given storage provider must support provisioning - this allows the cluster to request the provisioning of a "new" [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) when an unsatisfied [PersistentVolumeClaim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) pops up.

First make sure you have defined [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) properly. You have defined nfs-dynamic class but it is not defined as default storage class, that's why your claims cannot bound volumes to it. You have two options:
1. Execute command below:

```
  $  kubectl patch storageclass <your-class-name> -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'
```

2. Another option is to define in pvc configuration file storageclass you have used:

Here is an example cofiguration of such file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  storageClassName: slow
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      release: "stable"
    matchExpressions:
      - {key: environment, operator: In, values: [dev]}'
```

Simple add line  `storageClassName: nfs-dynamic`.

Then make sure you have followed steps from this instruction: [nfs-kubernetes](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/kubernetes/storage/use-nfs-volumes/).

Comment: Hi Maggie. Tanks for the suggestion. I made it default and still the same error on POD creation side. PV's and PVC's gets created on NFS side. Below the info I see. I have no idea how to add the mount points in the .json files? Is there a way to specify the mount points on NFS side as default?

Comment: /storage/dynamic$ ls
ganesha.log  nfs-provisioner.identity                  pvc-1c8d6834-9f5c-4723-963b-c1a41f348c10  pvc-b318f093-fc72-46dd-aff2-409799cdefcc
lost+found   pvc-00bcc4f8-92c0-4be3-91b3-2641834ca563  pvc-62849089-bd72-4c13-b354-a89e44da7e95  vfs.conf

Comment: kubectl get pvc -n mssql-cluster
NAME              STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
data-controldb    Bound    pvc-62849089-bd72-4c13-b354-a89e44da7e95   15Gi       RWO            nfs-dynamic    6m20s
data-controller   Bound    pvc-1c8d6834-9f5c-4723-963b-c1a41f348c10   15Gi       RWO            nfs-dynamic    6m20s
logs-controldb    Bound    pvc-00bcc4f8-92c0-4be3-91b3-2641834ca563   10Gi       RWO            nfs-dynamic    6m20s
logs-controller   Bound    pvc-b318f093-fc72-46dd-aff2-409799cd...

Comment: Did you specify nfs section in your pod configuration file with path label and eg. server ?